# java.io.FileNotFoundException? Unable to ouput data from excel file to console

Tags: java, maven

Output Student data to the Console

I have made the Student data into a List of Student objects, I want to output the contents of the List to the Console. I don't understand what this error means. Any clarification is much appreciated!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: scr\main\webapp\assets\JavaWebProgramming.xlsx
    at StudentMain.main(StudentMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: scr\main\webapp\assets\JavaWebProgramming.xlsx
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:271)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:252)
    at utility.WorkbookUtility.retrievePeopleFromWorkbook(WorkbookUtility.java:17)
    at StudentMain.main(StudentMain.java:16)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the code I believe is causing the error

```
import model.Person;
import utility.WorkbookUtility;
    
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
    
public class StudentMain {
    public final static String INPUT_FILE ="scr\\main\\webapp\\assets\\JavaWebProgramming.xlsx";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        final File inputFile = new File(INPUT_FILE);
    
        try {
            final List<Person>  people = WorkbookUtility.retrievePeopleFromWorkbook(inputFile);
        
            for(final Person person : people) {
                System.out.println(person);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're spelling the name of the first directory wrong. Also you should arrange that the path to the file be passed in to the program otherwise it becomes unmanageable

Comment: You should also not be referencing `src` in your code.  In this context, I would suggest looking at how "embedded resources" work, but if it's a "web app", this might require a different workflow

Comment: MadProgrammer is correct. You also need to get familiarized with how to properly create and use relative paths, particularly if inside your project.

Comment: I'm curious how do I go about arranging a path? I understand now my StudentMain class is unable to find my excel file. I thought adding a file under web app, that contains the excel file would work.  Then dependencies I am using are older versions and are highlighted in yellow Is there a way to fix that? Following videos instructed by my teacher...

Comment: It doesn't work for the reason I and others gave. It is difficult to know what the best way to treat the means of inputting the file path without knowing more about the app. Begin by correcting your spelling mistake